# How to save this varying property name to a single common property?

Tags: powershell

I have a custom "getter" that I built in PowerShell. I have been happy with it but I want to add one extra feature, a date for when the article was published.

This is something I  tried to do  a number of times but could never figure out due to the varying property name the RSS publishers give to the article's published date.

For example, getting latest feed from a Youtube channel and Muddcolors:

```
$url = "https://www.muddycolors.com/feed", "https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCB9bffMHdIBuvDq1KSelZAg"
$url |ForEach-Object {Invoke-RestMethod $_}
```

Muddy colours names its "date published" property `pubDate`, while YouTube  names its "date published" property `published`:

```
$url|ForEach-Object {Invoke-RestMethod $_}|obj title, pubdate,published |table    # omitted some properties for brevity


title                                                                   pubDate                         published
-----                                                                   -------                         ---------

Dear Santa…                                                             Mon, 04 Dec 2023 10:30:26 +0000
Messages to Your Creative Self                                          Fri, 01 Dec 2023 06:00:22 +0000
Couching Your Canvas and Cleaning Your Brushes                                                          2023-10-02T00:04:29+00:00
Color Mixing 01   North Light                                                                           2023-09-04T02:02:20+00:00
```

Currently I am getting the above kind of object. I would like `pubdate` and `published` to be under one column, like the following example:

```
title                                                                   published
-----                                                                   -------
Dear Santa…                                                             Mon, 04 Dec 2023 10:30:26 +0000
Messages to Your Creative Self                                          Fri, 01 Dec 2023 06:00:22 +0000
Couching Your Canvas and Cleaning Your Brushes                          2023-10-02T00:04:29+00:00
Color Mixing 01   North Light                                           2023-09-04T02:02:20+00:00
```

I tried a number of things to solve this issue when inside the `forEach-Object` loop but, closest I managed is:

```
$feed = $url | ForEach-Object {Invoke-RestMethod $_}

$feed | ForEach-Object {
     [PSCustomObject]@{
     Title            = $_.Title 
     Link            = $_.link
     dateCreated = $_.pubDate -eq $true ? $_.pubDate : $_.published
     }
}
```

Which does not even seem to work (some objects don't have a date value in them). Also with the growing number of RSS feeds I am thinking an `if`/`switch` block would scale badly.

How could I go about handling this in a more efficient manner?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is the ternary condition:

```
$_.pubDate -eq $true
```

It will always be `false` because `.pubDate` from those objects are a `string` not a `boolean`, `-eq $true` should be removed from that condition:

```
$_.pubDate ? $_.pubDate : $_.published
```

Since the objects from each URL are always the same what you could do is get the property name for each URL instead of for each object.

```
$url = @(
    'https://www.muddycolors.com/feed'
    'https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCB9bffMHdIBuvDq1KSelZAg'
)

$url | ForEach-Object {
    $property = $null

    foreach ($object in Invoke-RestMethod $_) {
        if (-not $property) {
            $property = $object.pubDate ? 'pubDate' : 'published'
        }

        [pscustomobject]@{
            Title       = $object.Title
            Link        = $object.link
            dateCreated = $object.$property
        }
    }
} | Format-List
```

As for scalability, if you will be querying more than 2 URL then using ternary operator will not be readable, it is recommended to use chained `if`, `elseif`.

```
$url | ForEach-Object {
    $property = $null

    foreach ($object in Invoke-RestMethod $_) {
        if (-not $property) {
            if ($object.pubDate) {
                $property = 'pubDate'
            }
            elseif ($object.published) {
                $property = 'published'
            }
            elseif ($object.otherProp) {
                $property = 'otherprop'
            }
            ...
        }
        ...
```

Using a `switch` would also be readable however to make it work you would need to use ScriptBlock conditions which are not really efficient compared to chained `if`, `elseif`.

```
$url | ForEach-Object {
    $property = $null

    foreach ($object in Invoke-RestMethod $_) {
        if (-not $property) {
            $property = switch ($object) {
                { $_.pubDate } { 'pubDate' }
                { $_.published } { 'published' }
                { $_.otherProp } { 'otherProp' }
            }
        }
        ...
```